# Express server not serving static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I'm using Express and socket.io to write an app, but my server can't find where the static files are. I realize this question has been asked multiple times, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me. I've tried different ways to reference the public folder with `express.static()` or to rearrange the code structure, but still no luck.

Code structure:

```
/node_modules
/public
    /css
        index.css
    /html
        index.html
    /js
/src
    /server
        /models
index.js
package.json
```

index.js:

```
// Get all modules needed
var express         = require('express'),
    http             = require('http'),
    bodyParser      = require('body-parser'),
    logger          = require('logger'),
    mongoose        = require('mongoose'),
    io              = require('socket.io'),
    path            = require('path'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    User = require('./src/server/models/user');

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/' + name);
var db = mongoose.connection;*/
var uristring =
    process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
    'mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose';

mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
    }
});

// Set up
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var ioServer = io(server);
app.use(bodyParser.json({}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + './public'));

// Connect to a socket
ioServer.on('connection', function(socket){
    // do something
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to serve the directory that contains the `index.html` file:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/html'));
```

You need to ensure the route specified is `/public/html` and not `./public/html`.

While this solves the problem, I'll recommend you place the `index.html` file at the root of your `public` directory. This is the recommended code structure:

```
/node_modules
/public
    /css
        index.css
    /js
    index.html
/src
    /server
        /models
index.js
package.json
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried "./public/html" but didn't really work. So I moved index.html to the root of public and tried "./public", still didn't work. What might be happening here?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I apologize for the error in my solution.

Comment: Worked like a miracle... Thanks so much!